# jquery mobile and google maps api sluggishness

Tags: jquery, google-maps, mobile

I am working with JQM 1 and gmap api v3. I am developing with an iphone for testing. I am noticing that while the map works on the phone it reacts to touch gestures a little sluggishly. I have also noticed if I open the map and then pan and zoom about too quickly it appears to get lost and on occassion freeze requiring a browser restart. Does anyone know if there is a way to stop further touch gestures being accepted on the phone until the map has finished doing what it is doing so that it is only ever trying to do one thing and does not get tangled up. Hope that makes some sense and thanks for any answers given.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can set up an event listener for the `tilesloaded` event (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map).  If that doesn't work, you can try out listeners on the `idle` event.

Here is an example of setting up an event listener:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html#EventListeners

I would also suggest determining why the sluggishness is occuring...the Maps API v3 is optimized to work with mobile browsers, so it may not necessarily be an issue with the API but with jQM + the API.

Cheers,

Andres

Comment: Thanks Andres - I'll take a look at 'tilesLoaded' (although am currently using 'idle' which I think is more or less the same). Thanks for the answer.